# How do I prevent my JPanel from readjusting

Tags: java, swing

I am making a java program that simulates how RGB works, 3 sliders with 3 corresponding canvases that change to the color value between 0 and 255. Also with one extra canvas showing the combination of the three colors. My problem is that when I begin to increase the values on the sliders my entire panel begins to stretch. I've been looking at the code now for a while with no luck. What do I need to change in order to either prevent the panel from adjusting or making the space bigger so an adjustment is not needed?

```
package javaapplication1;

/**
 *
 * @author Latez Bradley
 */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class RGBSlider extends JFrame {
  public RGBSlider() {
    getContentPane().add(new TColor());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1400, 1000);
    setVisible(true);
  }



  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new RGBSlider();
  }


}

class TColor extends JPanel {
  int n;
  DrawingCanvas canvas = new DrawingCanvas();
  DrawingCanvas rc = new DrawingCanvas();
  DrawingCanvas gc = new DrawingCanvas();
  DrawingCanvas bc = new DrawingCanvas();
  JLabel rgbValue = new JLabel("");
  JLabel red = new JLabel("<html>Red<br>Hex Value: "+n+"<br>Bin: "+n+"<html><br>Dec:"+n+"</html>");
  JLabel green =  new JLabel("<html>Green<br>Hex Value: "+n+"<br>Bin: "+n+"<html><br>Decimal: </html>"+n);
  JLabel blue = new JLabel("<html>Blue<br>Hex Value: "+n+"<br>Bin: "+n+"<html><br>Decimal: </html>"+n);



  JSlider sliderR, sliderG, sliderB;

  public TColor() {

    sliderR = getSlider(0, 255, 5, 255, 5);
    sliderR.setOrientation(1);
    sliderG = getSlider(0, 255, 0, 255, 5);
    sliderG.setOrientation(1);
    sliderB = getSlider(0, 255, 0, 255, 5);
    sliderB.setOrientation(1);


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout(4,3,200,0);
    panel.setLayout((myLayout));


    //panel.add(new JLabel("R-G-B Sliders (0 - 255)"));



    panel.add(sliderR);
    panel.add(red);
    rc.setSize(50, 50);
    panel.add(rc);

    panel.add(sliderG);
    panel.add(green);
    gc.setSize(50,50);
    panel.add(gc);

    panel.add(sliderB);
    panel.add(blue);
    bc.setSize(50,50);
    panel.add(bc);

    panel.add(new JLabel("RGB Value: ", JLabel.RIGHT));

    //rgbValue.setBackground(Color.white);
    //rgbValue.setForeground(Color.black);
    rgbValue.setOpaque(true);
    panel.add(rgbValue);


    canvas.setSize(300,300);
    add(canvas);
    add(panel);


  }

  public JSlider getSlider(int min, int max, int init, int mjrTkSp, int mnrTkSp) {
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, min, max, init);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(mjrTkSp);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(mnrTkSp);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());
    return slider;
  }

  class DrawingCanvas extends Canvas {
    Color color;
    Color rColor;
    Color gColor;
    Color bColor;
    int redValue, greenValue, blueValue;



    public DrawingCanvas() {
      setSize(350, 350);
      color = new Color(0, 0, 0);

      setBackgroundColor();


    }

    public void setBackgroundColor() {
      color = new Color(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
      setBackground(color);

      //red.setBackground(Color.white);
      //green.setBackground(gColor);
      //blue.setBackground(bColor);
    }
  }

  class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      JSlider slider = (JSlider) e.getSource();

      if (slider == sliderR) {
        canvas.redValue = slider.getValue();
        rc.redValue=slider.getValue();
        displayRGBColor();
        //red.setBackground(ColorR);
      } else if (slider == sliderG) {
        canvas.greenValue = slider.getValue();
        gc.greenValue = slider.getValue();
        displayRGBColor();
      } else if (slider == sliderB) {
        canvas.blueValue = slider.getValue();
        bc.blueValue=slider.getValue();
        displayRGBColor();
      }

      rc.repaint();
      red.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
      gc.repaint();
      bc.repaint();
      canvas.repaint();
    }

      public String toBin(int x){
      String temp="";
      while(x!=0){
              temp = (x%2)+temp;
              x/=2;
      }
      return temp;
    }



    public void displayRGBColor() {
      canvas.setBackgroundColor();
      rc.setBackgroundColor();
      gc.setBackgroundColor();
      bc.setBackgroundColor();

      //rgbValue.setText(Integer.toString(canvas.color.getRGB() & 0xffffff, 16));
      rgbValue.setText("<html> Hex Value: "+Integer.toString(canvas.color.getRGB() & 0xfffffff, 16)+"<br>Bin: "+toBin(sliderR.getValue())+""+toBin(sliderG.getValue())+""+toBin(sliderB.getValue()));
      red.setText("<html>Red<br>Hex Value: "+Integer.toString(canvas.color.getRed()  & 0xffffff, 16)+"<br>Bin: "+" "+"<html><br>Dec:"+sliderR.getValue()+"</html>");
      blue.setText("<html>Blue<br>Hex Value: "+Integer.toString(canvas.color.getBlue()  & 0xffffff, 16)+"<br>Bin: "+toBin(sliderB.getValue())+"<html><br>Dec:"+sliderB.getValue()+"</html>");
      green.setText("<html>Green<br>Hex Value: "+Integer.toString(canvas.color.getGreen()  & 0xffffff, 16)+"<br>Bin: "+toBin(sliderG.getValue())+"<html><br>Dec:"+sliderG.getValue()+"</html>");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't mix AWT (Canvas) and Swing components. Use all Swing components instead.

Comment: i had this problem when I was making a blackjack game and tried to display cards, every time the picture of a card popped up, the layout shifted. i believe it was using a grid layout, and it was a total disaster. Tag me in a comment if you find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't set sizes or preferred sizes. Instead let the components and the layout managers set the sizes for you.
2. Call `pack()` on your JFrame after adding components and before setting visible.
3. Don't use Canvas or other AWT components here. Use JPanels or JLabels.

Comment: I know this may seem a tad in appropriate as a comment, but how exactly did you teach yourself all the languages you know and concepts that you know despite not really attending college classes for programming? I'm looking to expand my knowledge and you seem to be very knowledgeable.